# Remote control with offline functionality | Home Automation

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, home-automation

I would like to control a particular light with a normal mechanical switch as well as using a mobile app.
The use case is as follows:-
If the mechanical switch is ON, I want the light to glow and it's switched off if the switch is OFF.
Even if the mechanical switch is ON, I want to switch it off using a mobile app (as well as ON).

So, should I implement a staircase wiring in this case? (I do not want to use Belkin switches, I plan to use a relay, ESP8266 and arduino and, ofcourse openhab).

Is this an old method? Is there a better way to implement the same?

Comment: Can you post photos of the switch boxes involved, or are you wiring this from scratch?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ThreePhaseEel. Actually, contruction of my house is going on, and the wiring works are round the corner (2-4 weeks). So, I just wanted to know more about this, so that I can try to proceed with the same.

Comment: Also, where are you on this planet?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Got any suggestions for my "smart switch" with offline capability case?

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement. You may have trouble getting good answers here to this mostly-electronic question. More details (e.g. a diagram) would help.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'll post it in IoT then. Thank you @DanielGriscom . I gave more preference to the DIY tag than "Home Improvement"! Once again, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Well yeah, your switch would have to be a three-way switch and your relay would need to be a SPDT with all three connectors used. Or you could have a switch that is simply touch sensitive or momentary contact and both that switch and your app control the same simple SPST relay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a smart (home automation) switch that *doesn't* have that "offline" capability.  I've got Insteon (Smarthome) switches in my house; they're Decora-style paddle switches with radio- and powerline connectivity. They talk to Insteon's "hub", which in turn talks to the cloud and your mobile app. You can turn the light on or off locally or remotely, and since they're bidirectional you can see on your smartphone whether a given light is on or off.  Is what you're looking to do any more complex than that?

Comment: Thank you @RussMcFatter This comes close. Is there any way to develop something like this? As in can we make a normal switch a smart switch? And then develop a hub so that we don't have to rely on 3rd party apps?

Comment: Yes and no. I don't think it's practical to build your own switch: certainly, with the correct parts, it's possible, but commercially available smart switches are lab-tested and certified; they won't burn your house down if they fail. They have secondary "air gap" switches as required by the standards bodies. You'd spend many more times on the effort than you would to just buy a switch. The controller is a different story. You could build or buy that; or even buy an adapter that connects to a computer, and write your own software for it. The protocols for most of these switches are well-known.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks a lot @RussMcFatter. What about using SONOFF switches? That can also be custom programmed with the help of MSQTT protocol and can be controlled using the openhab app, right?

Comment: I don't know anything about those in particular, but seems exactly like what they're designed for-- except the local control part (to work like a regular wall switch). They're cheap enough that I'd be tempted to buy one just to play with!  The whole IoT trend means you'll have a lot of options and resources to help you.